# C++: Propagation of information from child object to parent object

Tags: c++, oop

When working on software projects as a hobby, I have had my progress slow down or outright halt completely during the design process many times. Usually I stumble upon the same issues that I have already encountered before. One of such recurrent problems is about letting an object know what object should it contact or what object owns it:

Suppose we have an instance of class `Corporation` named `startup`, where one class `Supervisor` object and several class `Employee` objects work. The supervisor is responsible for assigning tasks to the employees, and helping the employees when they request for assistance. But the employees have to know *who is their supervisor* in order to report that they have finished working on their assignment, or for asking for something.

The problem is about how do I let the employees know who is this supervisor? I have come up with several solutions, but none of them seems to me like a definitive answer.

1. Make the `Supervisor` instance globally accessible, and have all `Employees` just call that instance directly: Avoiding globals is generally a good idea, but could this be an exception? I think not, and if the `startup` would ever grow to have more than one manager, problems would arise.
2. Adding a `static Supervisor *supervisor` member to the `Employee` class: This avoids the use of and problems related to global access, but retains the inability of having employees report to different managers when the `startup` grows.
3. Adding a `Supervisor *supervisor` member to the `Employee` class, and passing the `Supervisor` pointer to each `Employee` as a parameter of the employee's constructor: Very flexible, but inefficient in terms of memory usage when the `Employee` does not have many member variables.
4. Passing the `Supervisor` pointer as a parameter in every call of `Employee` member functions where the `Employee` might need to know who is the `supervisor`: Most flexible, but probably even less efficient than solution 3, and almost all member functions would require the supervisor parameter, resulting in additional overhead and unnecessary dependencies.
5. Making `Employee` a class template with a single non-type argument `Supervisor *S`: This would be as efficient as solution 1 or 2, but much more flexible. However, while the number of employees in `startup` could be changed at runtime, adding more supervisors to `startup` at runtime would be impossible, unless extra supervisors are created at compile time but left inactive. Additionally, I have no idea about how to create a copy constructor that takes one employee of a different but similar (template-created) type as an argument.

Comment: My current favourite solution is number 5, provided that a working copy constructor can be created, as my project can work with a fixed set of the equivalent of ´Manager` objects.

Comment: Have you arrived at this question after profiling and determining that the `Supervisor*` pointers are indeed a significant source of memory wastage in your program, compared to other usage of memory? Otherwise this seems like a clear case of premature optimization, and you shouldn't let it "slow down or outright halt" your development during the design phase. Go with the simplest solution that's conceptually correct -- #3. If it turns out to be a problem, revise your solution later.

Comment: Isn't the supervisor an employee? What about different departments? Does both HR and development have the same supervisor? What if you split development into several teams? The only reasonable solution is #3, and you will never have enough employees to make one pointer per employee be of any significance. Once you do, you use a database so you don't need to hold all employees in memory at once.

Comment: Even, if the company is a startup with about a million employees, you'd have an overhead of about 8 MB (on 64 bit) for the supervisor pointers. I can't image this being a problem at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving the `Employee` a pointer to its `Supervisor` is the traditional method for arranging for callbacks or progress reports. (That's your solution number three.) It's only one pointer. If you have enough employees that you're worried about the memory use (i.e. a few thousand of them), you can reduce the size by using a smaller handle rather than a pointer. That is, something like

```
typedef uint8_t SupervisorHandle;

class Employee {
    private:
    SupervisorHandle s;

    Supervisor& getSupervisor() {
        return startup.getSupervisor(s);
    }
    // ...
};
```

If you place the handle sensibly around your other fields, it need only take a byte, and now you can have up to 256 supervisors. But this comes at the cost of flexibility: it ties you to the static `Corporation` instance, and adds this non-obvious limit of 256 supervisors.

You've already noticed that your answers 1 and 2 limit you to a single `Supervisor`: if you're going to do that, why even have a class at all? Option 4, having the `Supervisor` passed in per-method, is actually no improvement: now the `Corporation` needs to have a map linking every `Employee` to the right `Supervisor`, and to look up in that map for every call. Introducing that kind of overhead to save a little memory is something you'd only do if you were desperately short. Option 5 limits you to statically allocated `Supervisor`s. You'd also need to create a template-free `EmployeeBase` class for the `Employee` class template to derive from, and unless `Employee` is already using inheritance, the vtable overhead would wipe out your memory saving.